# How to convert normal CrudRepository<T,ID> to ReactiveCrudRepository<T,ID>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using `spring-data-jpa` and `spring webflux`. When i am extending my UserRepository with `ReactiveCrudRepository`. i am getting below error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Reactive Repositories are not supported by DynamoDB. Offending repository is com.poc.crud.repository.EmployeeRepository!
```

If i extend with  `CrudRepository` and send response with `Mono.just(data-from-db)` and `Flux.just(data-from-db)` then every thing is fine.

**My question is , How can i create a custom generic `ReactiveCrudRepository<T,ID>` so that all crud method will return Mono and Flux objects.**

Comment: As the error mentions reactive isn't supported with DynamoDB. With a reguler repository you can return a `Mono` or `Flux` but it will be only handled async it isn't full reactive. Reactive DB support is only available for a small range of DB products and not the full range as with blocking access.

Comment: Thanks, there is a reactive library `r2dbc` , but still I am willing to write my own reactive implementation from normal `CrudRepository`

Comment: You cannot as that is blocking. Also you don't want to go down the path of writing your own reactive implementation. As long as you use JDBC underneath you cannot create a reactive implemnetation, you will need to reinvent R2DBC for that.

Comment: If I use `Mono.just()` to wrap the database response, is this still blocking code?

Comment: Yes as the underlying call is blocking. JDBC is blocking, no matter how much you wrap it with reactive types, underneath it is all blocking. So without a proper reactive driver (like R2DBC) the code is still blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If i extend with CrudRepository and send response with Mono.just(data-from-db) and Flux.just(data-from-db) then **everything is fine.**

Woah there - no, it's not. You might *think* it's all fine, but this is introducing blocking webcalls into a reactive chain, which will slow things down horrendously as soon as you have a few calls running in parallel. Worse than that, you've created a method that "looks" reactive, but isn't - commonly known as an "imposter reactive method".

Put simply, it's *impossible* to take blocking code and make it reactive - wrapping it in `Mono.just()` doesn't work. The library has to be built asynchronously from the ground up.

The bad news is that, as far as I'm aware, there's currently (Nov 2019) no `ReactiveCrudRepository` repository support for DynamoDB, so if you have to use this, you're a bit stuck.

The *good* news is that Amazon does now provide an [asynchronous client for DynamoDB](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbAsyncClient.html), and you can easily wrap a `CompleteableFuture` in a `Mono` by calling `Mono.fromFuture()` - so you could use that to stay reactive and still have DynamoDB support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was also looking for reactive support for dynamodb in aws sdk.